# How to get a nice view of data structure in debugger?

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, rogue-wave

I am debugging a Visual C++ project that uses Rogue Wave a lot. I would like to see content of RW containers easily, i.e. i want to see list elements instead of this:

[image]

What are my options? Can autoexp.dat do this?

Answer (score 2):

autoexp.dat can do it but it's quite difficult.

You can also write your own debugger extensions to visualize them, put them in a DLL and refer to it in autoexp.dat.  But again, this is quite difficult.

First see in autoexp.dat how the preview is defined for the standard STL containers (vector, list, map, string, ...), then try to mimic this for your own RWTIsvSlist class.